Cauchy product of absolutely convergent series
In Lang "Complex Analysis" (page 60) he gives a lengthy proof that if the power series $f= \sum a_n z^n, g = \sum b_n z^n$  both absolutely converge in some disc, then also their Cauchy product $f*g = \sum c_n z^n $, where $c_n =\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k b_{n-k} $ also converges in this disc and the limit of its partial sums equals the product of the limits of partial sums of $f$ and $g$.
I don't understand why the proof in the textbook is so complicated. Isn't the theorem implied by the rearrangement theorem for absolutely convergent series. 
Namely: $f= \sum a_n z^n, g = \sum b_n z^n$ both converge absolutely in some disc $|z|<R$ meaning the sequences of partial sums $ A_M = \sum_{n=0}^{M} |a_n| \rho^n \to A; \; \; B_M = \sum_{n=0}^{M} |b_n| \rho^n \to B$ converge when $0 \leq \rho<R$. By the product of converging sequences law $A_M B_M \to A B$. The Cauchy product $f*g$ is a rearrangement of the series whose partial sums are $ P_M(z) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{M} a_n z^n \right). \left(\sum_{n=0}^{M} b_n z^n \right)$. It was shown that $P_M$ is absolutely convergent in the disc $|z|<R$ and $P_M(z) \to f(z).g(z)$ (by the product rule for convergent sequences of partial sums), thus by the rearrangement theorem the Cauchy product $f*g(z)$ converges to the same limit as $P_M(z)$.

$\sum c_n z^n$ is not a rearrangement of the series whose partial sums are $ P_M(z)$, i.e. the series $\sum(P_{M+1}(z)-P_M(z))$.
